# Should a Promise.reject message be wrapped in Error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, es6-promise

Using the native (ES6) [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Should I reject with an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error):

```
Promise.reject(new Error('Something went wrong'));
```

Or should I just reject with a string:

```
Promise.reject('Something went wrong');
```

And what is the difference in browser behaviour?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference. You simply reject with a *value*. What that value is and how it is supposed to be processed depends on your application.

Comment: @FelixKling MDN does say *For debugging purposes, it is useful to make reason an instanceof Error* - it doesn't however say why, any ideas?

Comment: @RGraham: Where does it say that?

Comment: Sorry, on the docs page for [Promise.reject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject#Using_the_static_Promise.reject_method)

Comment: @RGraham: Probably for the reason Benjamin mentions in his answer, to get a stack trace. However, that's a characteristic of `Error`, not of passing an `Error` object to `.reject()`. The browser or JavaScript still doesn't care what you pass to `.reject()`.

Comment: Just like you can throw strings, but shouldn't.

Comment: You should use `new`: `Promise.reject(new Error('Something went wrong'));`

Comment: Also, in practice, just `throw new Error('Something went wrong'));` because inside promise-chains and Promise constructor executor functions, this turns into a rejection.

Comment: Related: [Throwing strings instead of Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, the rejection reason most definitely should be wrapped in `new Error()`. [A string is not an error](http://www.devthought.com/2011/12/22/a-string-is-not-an-error/), when you have errors usually it means something went wrong which means you'd really enjoy a good stack trace. No error - no stack trace.

Just like with try/catch, if you add `.catch` to a thrown rejection, you want to be able to log the stack trace, throwing strings ruins that for you.

I'm on mobile so this answer is rather short but I really can't emphasize enough how important this is. In large (10K+ LoC) apps stack traces in rejections really made the difference between easy remote bug hunting and a long night in the office.

Comment: Thanks I am also working on large apps glad that someone has had some practical experience with it

Comment: In all honesty? Consider Bluebird, it has better stack traces, typed `catch`, and unhabdled rejection tracking which are all killer features for debugging. ES6 promises work well so far only in Firefox in our experience.

Comment: 2022 update: Don't prefer bluebird, all the changes for debugging have been upstreamed to native promises. (Errors should 100% be wrapped in `new Error()`)

Comment: Also if you're rethrowing an error in a function that wraps another promise, you can pass the error from the catch param as the cause like this: `.catch((err)=>{reject(new Error('message ...', {cause: err}))})`

Answer (score 0):

I'm recommending to **use `Error` object only** (not a string) for sending the reasons.

#### Justification

Other parts of code are generating the `Errors` inside the Promise rejection reason...

If some code fails the exception returns the `Error` object. Also if you will call any external library, which does not support the Promise, it will throw the `Error` object when something fails.
If one of errors mentioned above occurs inside the Promise, it will be transformed into `catch` with `Error` object.

Therefore if you will use the `string` as promise rejection reason, you have to expect that the catch can occurs with your `string` (part of your code) or `Error` (when some general error occurs). So you will have to use ugly code `(err.message || err)` everywhere, when you have to handle the error.