# Transform values in a rejected promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Given I have a rejected promise:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  reject({error_message: "Foo"});
});
```

And I want to transform that promise (in that case: extract the error message):

```
var new_promise = promise.then(function(response) {
  return response.id;
}, function(error) {
  return error.error_message;
});
```

When I run that promise again:

```
new_promise.then(function(id) {
  console.log("Object created: "+id);
}, function(message) {
  console.log("Error: "+message);
});
```

I'll always get `Object created: Foo` on the console. It seems like the transformation turns the rejected promise into a resolved promise.

Is there a way to transform a rejected promise so the result is another *rejected* promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
return error.error_message;
```

you could use:

```
throw error.error_message;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Given I have a rejected promise:
>
> ```
> var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
>   reject({error_message: "Foo"});
> });
> ```

Notice this should read just `var promise = Promise.reject({error_message: "Foo"});` - no complicated constructor needing to be involved here.

> And I want to transform that promise

Specifically, you want to map over the error state of the promise. Unfortunately, there is no such method (such as `mapError`) on standard promises. What you have done in your code

> ```
> var new_promise = promise.then(…, function(error) {
>   return error.error_message;
> });
> ```

is actually setting up a *handler* for the error, not a transformation. You "catch" the error and then return a new *result* - see also [this control flow graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572).

> Is there a way to transform a rejected promise so the result is another rejected promise?

Yes, you need to get a rejection as the result of your handler. You can do that by either

```
.then(…, function(error) {
    return Promise.reject(error.error_message);
})
```

or by

```
.then(…, function(error) {
    throw error.error_message;
})
```

(however, notice that it is [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572) not to reject promises with actual `Error` objects)