# reject in promise undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, generator, co

I tried below function use `co` and javascript promise test, the `fulfill` will success return but `reject` not, and catch error undefined. and the flow can't continue. why?

Error:

```
> at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.next (native)
    at onFulfilled (/Users/../project/app/node_modules/co/index.js:65:19)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

Code:

```
domain.run(function() {

  var testPromise = function() {
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
      //reject('error');
      reject(new Error('message'));
    });
  };


co(function *() {
  var d = yield testPromise();
  console.log(d);
  res.send('fin');
}).catch(onerror);
function onerror(error) { console.error(error.stack); }

});
domain.on('error', function(error) { console.error(error); });
```

Comment: Is the `reject` argument itself undefined? Or is it perhaps because you passed a string to `reject()`, which doesn't have a `.stack` property (as referenced later in your code)?

Comment: You should always pass an Error object to the rejection handler. Either an existing error object or a `new Error('blah blah')`

Comment: if I remove the `catch`  the function promise still same , can't move to next function

Comment: Don't remove the catch. Instead, do `reject(new Error('error'))` in the above code. See what I mean?

Comment: I edit  but my problem  is the function is not keep moving to next just stop

Comment: So once you do that, do you not see a proper stack trace appear in the error console?

Comment: I see. `yield testPromise()` throws an error. You'll need to wrap try/catch around it, in order for lines of code immediately below it to run. Then if you do that, your `onerror` function shouldn't ever be called.

Comment: @greim but I wrap my code with `domain`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> catch error undefined

No. It catches the error `'error'`, the value you rejected with. Of course, it's not really an `Error` but a string, and as such it does not have a `.stack` property - that's why it logs `undefined`. Fix your code by doing

```
reject(new Error('…'));
```

See also [Should a Promise.reject message be wrapped in Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572)

> the flow can't continue. why?

Well, because you've got an error, and thrown [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) do have this behaviour. You'll also want to send a response in your error handler!

```
co(function *() {
  …
}).catch(function onerror(error) {
  console.error(error.stack);
  res.send('err');
});
```

Or if you intend to continue the flow at the call, put the `.catch` handler right there:

```
co(function *() {
  yield testPromise().then(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
  });
  res.send('fin');
});
```

Alternatively, wrap your promise call in a try-catch:

```
co(function *() {
  try {
    var d = yield testPromise();
    console.log(d);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error.stack);
  }
  res.send('fin');
});
```

Comment: I edit  but my problem  is the function is not keep moving to next just stop

Comment: So? Domains don't continue the flow either. I'm not sure where your misconception lies.

Comment: @user1775888: What is the expected result? How did you think your code would work?

Comment: I update the question, so the domain can't replace try catch?

Comment: @user1775888: Well, not if you need the `catch` *in* your flow. Btw, I don't see any reason to use domains here, promise callbacks (and `co`) are already throw-safe.

Comment: my expected result is browser print fin, I tried add try catch it works,  but if remove the try catch it stops, not execute after the promise , so I still have to add try catch in my code right?wrap with domain can't resolve this?

Comment: No, you just would have to put `res.send('err')` in your `onerror` function.

Comment: it just test there other function after,  and I tried to execute all done then render to browser

Comment: Yes, for that you'll have to catch each error individually. Either using `try catch` in your `co` generator, or by adding a `.catch(…)` handler on each promise.

Comment: the `catch` after  `co` can't get all inside the `co` wrap? , so maybe I should change the reject to fulfill too? to make it continue the flow

Comment: Well if you didn't intend to create an error, of course you shouldn't reject the promise in the first place. Not sure why you did that at all?

Comment: Can you show me example how to add catch after the `testPromise` should I chain after the `return new Promise ...  }).catch({ ...  });`