# Mongoose doesn't yield findeOne results in co

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, ecmascript-6, co

I'm using co and mongoose and I'd like to my asynchronous code look little more "synchronously" and - as far as I read - co library allows me use data from one yielded promise in another to avoid callback hell. It seems to work with mongoose save (even if I do multiple saves), but it does nothing with promises returned from queries like find() or findOne(). Why is that? What can I do to fix it?

Here'a a piece of my code:

```
co(function *() {
    let unhashedPassword = Math.random().toString(36);
    let passed = {
        username: 'T1',
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(unhashedPassword)
    };
    let saved = yield new test_model(passed).save();
    console.log("saved: " + saved);
    let found = yield test_model.findOne({username: saved.username}).exec();
    console.log("found" + found);
});
```

And the output:

```
saved: { _id: 57606dcf0f2378d41c355acd,
  password: '...',
  username: 'T1',
  __v: 0 }
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what if you just put `console.log("found");` ? does it reach that point ? seems weird you wouldn't even see the output from `console.log`

Comment: Try catching errors [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215520/1048572). I'm quite sure you've got an exception.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer, I did it after yieling test_model.findOne() and it's not printed - it doesn't  reach that point.

Comment: @Bergi - added the catch after co, even sorrounded findOne by try/catch and still nothing...

Answer (score 1):

What do you see when you try this ?

```
co(function *() {
    let unhashedPassword = Math.random().toString(36);
    let passed = {
        username: 'T1',
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(unhashedPassword)
    };
    let saved = yield new test_model(passed).save();
    console.log('saved: ', saved);
    let foundPromise = test_model.findOne({username: saved.username}).exec()
    .then(function(value){
        console.log('fulfilled', value);
    }, function(error){
        console.log('error', error);
    });
    console.log('foundPromise', foundPromise);
    let found = yield foundPromise;
    console.log('found', found);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log('catch', error);
});
```

Comment: I removed the last yield (let found = yield foundPromise yield):
saved:  { _id: 57607fcf7cfca7980d37bc12,
  password: '$2a$10$Ebk6vFc5iai7yt7wTnT16e.0fOxEyvUE0jUqemYho44MfLUiACI0u',
  username: 'T1',
  __v: 0 }
foundPromise Promise {
  emitter: 
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: { reject: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined },
  emitted: {},
  ended: true }
Process finished with exit code 0