# Why does Promise.reject() require a return?

Tags: javascript, promise, return-value

In the following code the `Promise.reject` doesn't work unless I specifically use `return Promise.reject(...)`. Why is this?

```
Promise.resolve('Promise 1 Done')
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  return 'Promise 2 Done'
}).then(function(result) {
  let j;
  try {
    j = JSON.parse("invalid will throw");
    console.log(j);
  } catch(err) {
    Promise.reject('Could not parse JSON');
  }

  console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.reject` creates a value, it does not throw an exception that breaks from the function like `throw` does. If you don't `return` that value, it will be ignored and the control flow continues.

Given you are inside a promise callback, you could (and possibly should) instead use

```
throw new Error('Could not parse JSON');
```

Comment: Or return the rejected promise with `return Promise.reject('Could not parse JSON');`.

Comment: @jfriend00: the OP knows that already, so yes :-) But [don't forget to wrap the message in an `Error`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572).

Comment: And I didn't think your answer illustrated the two options available in this context which would be useful for other readers too. Just suggesting an improvement. OP may also be confused about the difference between calling reject in a promise constructor vs this situation.