# Promise error propagation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this function which will if it fails retry, and if it fails x times it should finally reject the Promise. I have implemented this as follows:

```
examplefunction(retries = -1) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const url = `example.org`;
            const json = await this._sendRequest(url);
            resolve(json);
        } catch (e) {
            if( retries > 0 ) {
                return this.examplefunction(retries - 1);
            }
            else {
                reject("Unable to communicate with Server. Please try again later!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the function is beeing called like this:

```
backend.examplefunction(3).then(
    (json) => {
        console.log(json);
    },
    (reason) => {
        console.log.(reason);
    }
)
```

This code is executed in a React context, so it is also running through a babel transpilitaion.

My problem is that when it will finally reject after x retries this results in a Uncaught Promise Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Unable to communicate with Server. Please try again later!!
```

[image]

Could anybody explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: does it log the reason ("error") before throwing the exception?

Comment: yes, see the screenshot I have added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), and never pass an `async function` to it! You should write

```
async function example(retries = -1) { /*
^^^^^ */
    try {
        const url = `example.org`;
        const json = await this._sendRequest(url);
        return json;
//      ^^^^^^
    } catch (e) {
        if (retries > 0) {
            return this.examplefunction(retries - 1);
//          ^^^^^^ this works as expected now
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unable to communicate with Server. Please try again later!");
//          ^^^^^
        }
    }
}
```

You were never `resolve`ing the promise in the retry case, and when the recursive call failed eventually then that promise was completely ignored.

Comment: Thanks this cleared it. One thing I don't quite understand however is the following:
When using the Antipattern approach and rejecting, the onRejected Function will receive a String with the error message, in this approach however it will receive an error object.

Comment: Yes, I just changed it (without a comment) because [you should always reject with errors, not strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572). You could of course `throw` the string literal if you insisted.