# Why is my expected rejection not a success case in mocha using chai-as-promise?

Tags: typescript, promise, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I want to assert a promise rejection in a mocha test case. Hence I do this in typescript:

```
import {
    expect,
    use,
} from "chai";
import * as chaiAsPromised from "chai-as-promised";

use(chaiAsPromised);

describe("Promise rejection", async () => {

    it("should assert promise rejection", async () => {
        const msg = "I AM THE EXPECTED ERROR";

        const rejectedPromise = Promise.reject(msg);

        return expect(rejectedPromise).to.eventually.throw(msg);

    });
});
```

I expect my test case to be successful, as the expected error is thrown. Yet my test fails with:

```
Error: the string "I AM THE EXPECTED ERROR" was thrown, throw an Error :)
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Comment: What promise library are you using? In case of Bluebird, this is [a normal warning](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error) - you [should reject with `Error`s not with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to test for a *promise* rejection, not an *error*. Hence use `rejectedWith`:

```
return expect(rejectedPromise).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith(msg);
```