# Promise not terminating after reject() call

Tags: typescript, promise, async-await

Hi I am trying to check for invalid cases before executing a database action. For some reason my code will run `reject('Invalid E-mail address.');` but then it will also continue to run the `await User.findOne({email})` line. There are several ways I can rewrite this but I would like to keep the current structure of this code. How can I terminate the function after reject and prevent the rest of the code from running? Thanks

user.database.ts

```js
export const registerUser = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<User> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        // check if email or password are null
        if (!email || !password) {
            reject('Invalid E-mail address or Password.');
        }

        // check if email is invalid
        if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
            reject('Invalid E-mail address.');
        }

        // check if database already contains E-mail address
        await User.findOne({email}).then((user: any) => {
            if (user) {
                reject('E-mail address already in use.'); // code should stop here
            }
        });

        // anything below should not run

        // create user object
        const user = new User({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            email: email,
            password: password
        });

        // save user object to database
        await user.save().then((result: any) => {
            resolve(result);
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
};
```

auth.controller.ts

```js
export const register = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    registerUser(email, password).then((user: User) => {
        res.status(200).json(user);
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        res.status(300).json(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: (1) The `new Promise()` wrapper is an antipattern here. Nothing needs to be promisified. (2) `resolve` is not the same as `return`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 so i should scrap the idea of using a promise? i added the way i use this function.

Comment: No, just scrap the idea of having a `new Promise()` wrapper. As `registerUser()` is `async`, it will (1) automatically wrap any returned value in Promise, (2) throw asynchronously, (3) allow the use of `await`.

Comment: Also could utilize `return reject()`, `return resolve()`. Returns out and prevents continuation.

Comment: Avoid mixing `await` and `.then()`. Whereas the language allows them to be mixed, they are alternative syntaxes, to the same end.

Comment: @NSTuttle, straightforwardly yes but `resolve` and `reject` will disappear when the unnecessary `new Promise()` wrapper is removed.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 makes sense now that I looked into the async patterns/behaviors. Cool that it unwraps in-line, much more elegant as well. Thanks for the teaching moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `new Promise()` inside an `async` function is an antipattern: an `async` function *already* returns a promise, so you only need to explicitly return the value that promise should *resolve* to.

The issue you describe is caused by the fact that you don't exit your function once you know its failure reason: the function will still continue the rest of the code if you don't also `return` or `throw`.

Tackling both issues, your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
const registerUser = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<User> => {
    if (!email || !password) {
        throw new Error('Invalid E-mail address or Password.');
    }

    if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid E-mail address.');
    }

    let user: any = await User.findOne({email})
    if (user) {
        throw new Error('E-mail address already in use.');
    }

    user = new User({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        email: email,
        password: password
    });

    return user.save();
};
```

Note that `throw` inside an `async` function will make the promise (that the `async` function *always* returns) reject with the reason you provide.

Note also that in the case of success, the resolution value is here a promise (`user.save()`), so that means the promise of the `async` function will link its resolution to the resolution of *that* promise.

Comment: Always throw `Error`.

Comment: Changed. Jeninja, please note that after applying Roamer's suggestion, you'll get rejection reasons as Error instances, not as plain strings. See also [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020578/should-a-promise-reject-message-be-wrapped-in-error)