# Acceptable parameters inside promise.resolve() and reject()

Tags: javascript, promise

What are acceptable arguments when it comes to the resolve() and reject() methods inside a promise object?

I typically see strings and numbers. 
I assume most other data types in js? i.e. objects, functions, arrays etc.

```
let x = new 
Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  resolve("string");
  reject("error");
});
```

Comment: Absolutely anything

Comment: @CertainPerformance Cool thank you!

Comment: A promise is an abstraction of a 'value available at some time in the future' (which may mean 'never'). Therefore it is kind of a wrapper/placeholder for the actual value, which may be any JS expression (even another promise). Note that the time `resolve`/`reject` will be called is usually not known beforehand - think of any async operation like calling an url, reading a file, querying a db.

Comment: Note that calling *both* `resolve` and `reject` inside the Promise is definitely not what your users will expect. The expectation is that exactly one will be called.

Comment: Resolve with any type. Reject will also accept any type but you should always reject with an Error object ... reason being, (a) so your error handlers know what to expect, (b) makes the stack trace available to error handlers.

Comment: Please [always reject your promises with an `Error`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572).

Answer (score 2):

`resolve()` can be called with any Javascript type.  All it does is pass that value straight through to the whoever is listening to the host promise with `.then()` or `await`.

The one exception is if you resolve it with a "thenable" (anything that behaves like a promise object), then that promise itself will be waited for and the resolved value of the original promise will become the resolved value of that new promise.

In fact, there's no way to directly resolve to a promise itself because `resolve()` will detect that you resolved to a promise and will chain to it.  If you ever had a reason to do that, you would have to wrap the promise in an object and resolve with the object.

There's nothing stopping you from passing any Javascript value to `reject()` either, but it is an often-practiced convention to reject with Error objects and there's a fair amount of error handling code that can be simpler or easier or may even expect you to use Error objects.  It also has the advantage of offering you a stack trace (though sometimes a smaller asynchronous stack trace) that will at least tell the caller where the error originated if they need more info about what might have happened.  But, there's nothing in the standard or implemented in the language that requires you to `reject()` with an error object.

You may also want to note that your example calls `resolve("string")` and then calls `reject("error")`.  A promise is a one-shot device.  The first `resolve()` or `reject()` that gets called is the only one that gets paid any attention to - any subsequent calls to either are simply ignored.  A promise "latches" the first resolved value or reject reasons you give it and can never be changed after that.