# Code continues to execute after promise is reject in await expression

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Run the following code in chrome console and you can see the console log being printed. Why is it getting printed even after the error is thrown by `f2()` ?

```
async function f1() {
 const p  = await f2();
 console.log("This line should not get printed since the promise was rejected");
}

async function f2() {
    Promise.reject("promise rejected");
}

f1();
```

Comment: You should reject your promisse with an `Error`. Try this: `Promise.reject( Error("promise rejected") )`

Comment: try `return`ing the rejection - otherwise the calling function has no clue what happened

Comment: @NoNam4 that's not how rejection works, i.e. it doesn't have to be of type Error

Comment: @JaromandaX according to [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/prefer-promise-reject-errors) rejections should be an Error type: `It is considered good practice to only pass instances of the built-in Error object to the reject() function for user-defined errors in Promises.`

Comment: @NoNam4 eslint is wrong - again - oh "good practice" ... that's nice, it's also good practice to wash your hands after going to the toilet, but it's not a rule

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a rule that [you really should follow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572) though, even if it's technically not required. Just like there is [no good reason to `throw` non-`Error` exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572)

Comment: "*…after the error is thrown by `f2()`?*" - well `f2()` didn't throw an error, that's the problem. You would need to `await` (or `return`) the `Promise.reject(…)`, or you should actually `throw` an exception from the `f2` code - that's how `async function`s work.

Comment: @Bergi my point was in relation to this code - the type of rejection is completely irrelevant to the *problem* - also, there are enough libraries that return a Promise that *reject* something that isn't an `Error` that makes the point moot.

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess that's why NoNam4 posted a comment, not an answer… And libraries employing bad practices doesn't make the practice any less bad - just more common.

Comment: I agree @Bergi - I also agree with most (definitely not all) of jslint's "good practice" *suggestions* - however, is any of that relevant to the problem? it's just noise that detracts from the solution - having said that, it's probably not a bad idea to instil *good practices* earlier rather than later - point well made

Comment: @Bergi - you do realise I'm now combing through my code for "bad practice" rejections :p

Comment: @JaromandaX got it. It worked like I was expecting it to work after returning the rejected promise from f2()
One more thing, JS wraps the value returned by async functions. So, in my case Promise.reject"promise rejected") will again be wrapped in a promise whose resolved value will be promise - Promise.reject"promise rejected") ?

Comment: no idea what you're saying with code that isn't even valid

Comment: JS wraps async function returned value around a Promise right?

Comment: sorry for the above comment
Since I am already returning a promise , this returned value won't be wrapped around a promise

Comment: *"since I am already returning a promise"*: no, you're not, and that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing is because you're not handling the rejection of the Promise returned by f2() properly. When the `Promise.reject("promise rejected")` is executed, it creates a rejected Promise, but you're not handling that rejection.

To fix this and similar issues you should always use `try-catch` blocks for side effects, in this case you could do this:

```js
async function f1() {
  try {
    const p = await f2();
    console.log("This line should not get printed since the promise was rejected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error); // If you want you can ignore logging anything
  }
}

async function f2() {
  return Promise.reject("promise rejected");
}

f1();
```

Comment: you don't HAVE to use try/catch to make the code work as expected, and in some cases, you may not, if a higher up function (one that calls f1 for example) handles the rejection ... the only relevant part of this answer is the `return`

Comment: @JaromandaX I do get your point but how else do you suggest handling the rejection if not using catch, you do have to catch it somewhere? Just using the `return` will leave a unhandled promise rejection here because there is no higher up function.

Comment: the question wasn't about *handling the rejection*, it was about why did the code continue :p my comment wasn't at all saying your answer was wrong

Comment: …also you could use `f1().catch(console.error)`

Comment: @Bergi - exactly my point in the first comment