# Try/catch block not working as expected with array of variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, try-catch

I have a function that uses 3 variables and a try catch. I want to use the 3 variables as part of an array but if i do i cannot complete the try catch and function correctly

JS:

```
function calculateVolume() {

    length = document.getElementById("Length").value;
    width = document.getElementById("Width").value;
    height = document.getElementById("Height").value;
    try {
        if ((length > 1000) || (width > 1000) || (height > 1000))
            throw "err"
        else
            var volume = length * width * height;
        alert(volume);
    } catch (err) {
        alert("You have not entered all three dimensions correctly");
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Your code works fine. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: As a note: while it is possible to throw what every you want as an error in js, you still should use a real Error object. You might want to read the  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27501348/1960455) to the question [Throwing strings instead of Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502052)

Comment: @tymeJV possibly you don't know but in js [var_hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Comment: Where does the array come into this - I'm not seeing it? Are length, width and height meant to be in an array?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you want `length`, `width`, and `height` in an array and you want the condition to check their relevant values.

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), as in:

```
arr.some(function (el) { return el > 1000; });
```

This example which would throw an error:

```
var a = 1000,
    b = 1000,
    c = 2000;

var arr = [a, b, c];

try {
    if (arr.some(function (el) { return el > 1000; })) {
        throw "err"
    } else {
        console.log('no error')
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log("You have not entered all three dimensions correctly");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/9ew58zLz/)