# NodeJS clarity around promises

Tags: node.js, promise

Beginning my first significant NodeJS app and I am unsure if I am leveraging promises properly. In my case I am sending an AJAX request and then once it's done want to return something (In this case send back a specific status code and message to the browser). I'm doing additional validation in the then block but I'm not sure if I'm executing this right. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);
```

...

```
request({
        url: 'https://my.url.com', //URL to hit
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'MyContentType',
            'Custom-Header': 'Custom Value'
        },
        body: jsonStringVar //Set the body as a string
    }).then(function (resp) {
        if(resp.headers.status != "200") {
            throw (401)
        }
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(resp.headers.status);
        res.status(201);
        res.json({
            "status": "Success"
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500);
        res.json({
            "status": "bam"
        });
    });
```

I feel like I'm incorrectly checking the resp.header.status in the chained function and throwing an error. Is there a better way to do custom validation and throw an error or would this be the accepted practice to error out a promise?

Comment: Are you asking about `request` and whether `resp.headers.status != "200"` is correct, or are you asking about promises and whether `throw 401;` is appropriate?

Comment: Promises and whether throw 401 would be the appropriate way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is throwing an error the accepted practice to error out a promise?

Yes, it is. Promises were designed to do that, it's quite equivalent to throwing exceptions in a synchronous function and catching them with a `try` statement. Of course you can also use `if` else for conditional validation tasks, but throwing is fine.

What you should not do is to throw the number `401`, better [always throw `Error` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572).

Comment: Thanks! I was throwing the 401 more for simplicity at this point but agree should be using a proper error object even in mocking.