# Efficient method for building a promise object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

At the moment what I have is this :

```
    getData(user) {
     return this.$q.all({
        userInfo: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getinfo', user)),
        userTopArtists: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.gettopartists', user)),
        userChart: this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyChartList', user))
            .then(resp => {
                let promises = [];
                let data = resp.data.weeklychartlist.chart;
                for (let i = data.length - 4; i < data.length; i++) {
                    promises.push(
                        this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyTrackChart', user) + `&from=${data[i].from}&to=${data[i].to}`)
                        .then(resp => {
                            return resp.data.weeklytrackchart.track.length;
                        })
                    );
                }

                return this.$q.all(promises);
            })
    }).then(resp => {
        return resp;
    }).catch(err => {
        this.$q.reject('Error' + err.status);
    })
}
```

But I'm thinking there may be a more functional approach to building this promise object, because a lot of code is getting repeated. So I tried to come up with a better solution:

```
    buildPromiseObj(target) {
     const methods = ['getinfo', 'gettopartists', 'getweeklychartlist'];
     let obj = {};
     for ( let method in methods ) {
        obj[`${methods[method]}`] = this.$http.get(this.buildUrl(`${target}.${methods[method]}`, target))
    }
}
```

1. Does this approach make sense and should I use it ?
2. You can see that the 3rd request I make in the first function has other nested requests. Is there any way I can integrate that in the approach I've written above ?

Comment: Personally I would keep as is, this `buildPromiseObj` has gained very little, and only provided you with another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's always a good idea to generalise like this. However:

- [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)
- `` `${methods[method]}` `` is pointless use of template strings
- your method/property names are inconsistent about capitalisation and prefix (`user…` vs `get…`)
- [Drop the pointless `.then(resp => { return resp; })`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41089122/1048572)
- Your `catch` callback doesn't do anything. It should at least have `return`ed the rejected promise - or simply `throw`n the error. Also [you should not reject with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572).

Regarding the chart list, you can just append another `then` to the promise before calling `all`. Also you can greatly simplify the callback by using a more functional approach:

```
getData(user) {
    const methods = ['Info', 'TopArtists', 'WeeklyChartList'];
    let promises = {};
    for (let method of methods) {
        obj['user' + method] = this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.get'+method.toLowerCase(), target));
    }
    promises.userWeeklyChartList = promises.userWeeklyChartList.then(resp =>
         this.$q.all(resp.data.weeklychartlist.chart.slice(-4).map(val =>
             this.$http.get(this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyTrackChart', user) + `&from=${val.from}&to=${val.to}`)
         ).then(resp =>
             resp.data.weeklytrackchart.track.length
         ))
    );
    return this.$q.all(promises).catch(err => {
        throw new Error(err.status);
    });
}
```

Comment: Appreciat the in depth response, however I'm getting this wierd error, that I've been trying to solve for the past half hour

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined at promises.userweeklychartlist.promises.userweeklychartlist.then.resp`

Comment: weeklychartlist is undefined here: let data = resp.data.weeklychartlist.chart;

Comment: @TudorApostol Did you write a dot instead of the assignment? There is no `promises.userweeklychartlist.promises.userweeklychartlist.th‌​en.resp` anywhere. The only place where a `.data` property is accessed is `resp.data.weeklychartlist`

Comment: @MichaelRosefield Not sure what you mean, there is no `let data` statement in the code in my answer

Comment: @Bergi I've reproduced the code exactly as you've written it, thats why I'm having problems with why this error would occur.

Comment: @TudorApostol Make sure `resp.data` is what you expect and contains a `.weeklychartlist`. Notice that my code calls `this.buildUrl('user.getweeklychartlist', …)` instead of `this.buildUrl('user.getWeeklyChartList', …)`, as necessary for the generalisation.

Comment: @Bergi It was a typo in `user.getweeklychartlist`. God, I love coding.

Comment: @Bergi Any ideea why the nested requests are not getting called at the same time as the other requests ?

Comment: @TudorApostol If by "nested requests" you mean those constructed inside `promises.userWeeklyChartList.then(…)`, then obviously that is because they have to wait for the weekly chart list to know what needs to be fetched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159083/discussion-between-tudor-apostol-and-bergi).

Comment: @bergi, ah, sorry, I thought they were experiencing the issue with their original code

Answer (score 1):

As a first pass, here's what I would do with it.

```js
        
const { $http: { get }, $q: { all } } = this,
      // convert { x: 'a', y: 'b' } to '&x=a&y=b'
      paramStr = obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v]) => `&${k}=${v}`).join(), // You might not have Object#entries; it's new
      
      getUrl = (target, method, params={}) => this.buildUrl(`user.get${method}`, target) + paramStr(params),

      getData = user => all(Object.assign({},
        ...['info', 'topartists', 'WeeklyChartList'].map(m => get(getUrl(user, m)))
      ))
        .then(([ userInfo, userTopArtists, { data: { weeklychartlist: { chart } } } ]) => 
          all({
            userInfo, 
            userTopArtists,
            userChart: all([
                ...chart.slice(-4)
                  .map(({ from, to }) => 
                    get(getUrl(target, 'WeeklyTrackChart', { from, to }))
                      .then(({ data: { weeklytrackchart: { track: { length } } } }) => length)
                  )
              ])
          })
        )
        .catch(({ status }) => this.$q.reject(`Error${status}`));
```

I'm keeping your code functionally the same, though Bergi's recommendations are good ones.