# How to put restriction in a class constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The constructor function of the `Interpolation` class takes in two arrays. How can I set a restriction so that during object creation the length of these two arrays must be equal.

```
class Interpolation {
    constructor (x, fx) {
        if ( x instanceof Array && fx instanceof Array ) {
            if ( x.length === fx.length ) {
                this.input = x;
                this.output = fx;
            } else { throw 'Unmatching array' }
        } else throw 'Please pass in array';
    }
}
```

I tried this and during object creating the source code was also printed on the console like this

```
C:\NeuralNetwork\interpolation.js:7
                        } else { throw('Invalid Array') }
                                 ^
Invalid Array
```

Comment: What should happen when the arrays are of different length?

Comment: @gurvinder372  throw an error

Comment: You are already doing that. What is it that you need help with?

Comment: Apart from that [you should not throw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572), your code seems fine?

Comment: @gurvinder372 My problem is the error is showing the source code which doesn't seem tidy

Comment: @Aditya That's just the debugger trying to help you, showing where the error originated from and a stack trace. That's what exceptions do. Catch the error and it won't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
class Interpolation {
    constructor (x, fx) {
        if(!(x instanceof Array)) {
            throw('parameter `x` must be an Array.');
        }

        if(!(fx instanceof Array)) {
            throw('parameter `fx` must be an Array,');
        }

        if(x.length !== fx.length) {
            throw('the length of these two arrays(x, fx) must be equal');
        }

        this.input = x;
        this.output = fx;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better ?