# Throwing String vs string

Tags: javascript, string, throw

I'm having an issue with throwing an error type `string`. I've spent twenty minutes looking at all the other questions, implementing them into my own code. Most of them are related to C# and Java, and only closest one I've found was in TypeScript, which didn't work.

The goal is to throw a `string` when the array is null or the length is zero. I've tried the tens of ways they describe it on this website, to no avail. The link to this question is [here](https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/javascript/arrays/minAndMax).

```
function minAndMax(arr) {
    if(arr === null || arr.length == 0) { throw "array must contain at least one value"; }
    let min = arr[0];
    let max = arr[0];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < min) { min = arr[i]; }
        if(arr[i] > max) { max = arr[i]; }
    }
    console.log("Minimum Value = " + min);
    console.log("Maximum Value = " + max);
}
```

I am given the following error:

```
expected exception: string
your exception:     String: array must contain at least one value
```

I've researched `String vs string literal` and any other case that it related to this, but I've found no help. There are examples that *work* and they use the same syntax as I do, but mine doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something…what is giving you the error `expected exception: string` is that a test? a linter?  -- sorry I just clicked the link.

Comment: @MarkMeyer The CodeStepByStep website. When I submit the answer, it returns the error provided. I’ve tried refreshing/leaving the website, and resubmitting, but it still doesn’t work.

Comment: It says *"throw an exception with the message..."*, are you sure you should be throwing a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe “throw new Error(...);” doesn’t work

Comment: Then I'd suggest following the instructions under **Need help?**

Comment: I think the site's just derped. I've tried throwing a lot at it and I have no clue. I even tried creating a custom object called StringException (it complained it was an object), and creating a custom class (complained about the `class` keyword), and returning and printing instead of throwing...

Comment: Similar error for other problems that require throwing an exception. I think they just messed up JS exception handling on their end. The same problems work fine in other languages wrt exceptions being thrown.

Comment: …and yes, [you should not throw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572) anyway.

Comment: @Bergi The numerous articles I read agree with your statement, as do I, but the exercise requires that **strings** must be thrown.

Comment: Yes, and this lets me question the usefulness of that website :-) As Carcigenicate observed, the exercise just doesn't seem to work. You might want to contact the author, or just carry on. I'll vote to close this question as off-topic or too broad since we cannot access the code of the test that is failing.