# Which data type could contain in `error` parameter of "catch` clause (JavaScript/TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My function:

```
buildErrorMessage(
  {
    originalError,
  　// ...
  }: {
    originalError?: Error;
    // ...
  }): string 
{ 
  /* ... */ 
}
```

When I try to use this function in catch block, the rule [no-unsafe-assignment](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-assignment.md) of [typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint) tells me that I trying to assign the value of `any` type:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(buildErrorMessage({
    originalError: error,
    // ...
  }));
}
```

Well, which data `error` could contain besides `Error`?

Comment: "Use Typescript," they said. "It'll help prevent mistakes," they said. (Just joking, but you can also `throw` strings? Maybe that's the issue?)

Comment: @Christian, thank you for witty comment! If no troublesome formalities required when open new issue in TypeScript repository, I'll open this issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript is right here: `any` value can be `throw`n and will get caught in your `catch` clause. Sure, [it's best practice to throw `Error` instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572), but Typescript won't assume that you do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Got it. I suppose, I should annotate `originalError` as `unknown`.