# Async await only output error message in catch

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I have the following async function:

```
async function register() {
  try {
    if (password1 !== password2) {
      throw "Passwords do not match!";
    }
    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1)
  }

  } catch (err) {
    document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = err;
    return;
  }
```

The first password match checks if the password entered by the user two times are identical. If they are, then use Firebase to create an account. But Firebase's `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function return an `error` object that contains a `error.code` and a `error.message`. I only want to display the `error.message` and disregard the `error.code`. Is it possible to do it with the common `catch` block following the try, or I have to write a specific `catch` block for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to disregard the error code?

Comment: [Don't throw string values!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572) If you do `throw new Error("passwords do not match");` the `err` will be an object and have a `.message` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to match the structure of firebase in your
Throw error condition using

```
   throw { message: 'Passwords do not match!' };
```

And then always deal with the error as an object
In both cases

Edit:

Thanks to Bergi, you can also use this approach which is even better

```
   throw new Error('Passwords do not match!);
```

Which will also create an object with a message attribute

Comment: Or even better, `throw new Error("passwords do not match");` or even `throw new PasswordMismatchError()`

Comment: Thanks, i knew something was missing :D