# "await is only valid in async function" in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm being told that "await is only valid in async function", even though it is in a async function. Here is my code:

```
async function uploadMultipleFiles (storageFilePaths,packFilePaths,packRoot) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            for (i in storageFilePaths) {
                await uploadFile(storageFilePaths[i],packFilePaths[i],packRoot) // error throws on this line
            }
            resolve("files uploaded")
        } catch {
            console.log(err)
            reject("fail")
        }
    })
}
```

Why is this happening when I made it an async function? Is it because I am using a for loop? If so, how can I get the expected outcome without this error?

Comment: The relevant function here is the lambda you've declared for the promise, not uploadMultipleFiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you define starting on line 1 is `async`.

The arrow function you define on line 2 and pass to the Promise constructor is **not** async.

---

You are also using the *multiple promise anti-pattern*. Get rid of the Promise constructor entirely. Just return the value when you have it. That's one of the main benefits of the `async` keyword.

```
async function uploadMultipleFiles(storageFilePaths, packFilePaths, packRoot) {
    try {
        for (i in storageFilePaths) {
            await uploadFile(storageFilePaths[i], packFilePaths[i], packRoot) // error throws on this line
        }
        return "files uploaded";
    } catch {
        console.log(err);
        throw "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I call `uploadMultipleFiles` later in the code, it's in an async function and its called as `await uploadMultipleFiles`. If I get rid of the promise here, how would I be able to `await` it later?

Comment: @pufferfish — `async` functions always return promises

Answer (score 2):

You can only use **`await`** inside of an **`async`** function, the error refers to the callback your passing to your new **`Promise`**  (since you are entering a new function scope there).

```
async function uploadMultipleFiles (storageFilePaths,packFilePaths,packRoot) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => { // <========= this arrow function is not async 
      try {                                // so you cant use await inside
          for (i in storageFilePaths) {
              await uploadFile(storageFilePaths[i],packFilePaths[i],packRoot) // error throws on this line
          }
          resolve("files uploaded")
      } catch {
          console.log(err)
          reject("fail")
      }
  })
}
```

The part where you try to construct a new **`Promise`** is actually redundant since an `async` function will resolve to a `Promise` anyways (read more [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). So you could write your code as follows:

```
async function uploadMultipleFiles (storageFilePaths,packFilePaths,packRoot) {
  try {
      for (i in storageFilePaths) {
          await uploadFile(storageFilePaths[i],packFilePaths[i],packRoot) // error throws on this line
      }
      return "files uploaded"
  } catch {
      console.log(err)
      throw new Error("fail");
  }
}
```

Comment: `reject("fail")` and `return "fail"` are not equivalent. A `reject` and a `throw` are equivalent.

Comment: @t.niese true, resolve('fail') would be the equivalent in my case, good catch. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Just some nitpicking `reject("fail")` and `throw new Error("fail");` are also not equivalent.  `reject("fail")`  and  `throw "fail";`  are or `reject(new Error("fail"))` and `throw new Error("fail")`. But I agree that in both cases an `Error` (or a class inheriting from it) should be used.

Comment: @t.niese agreed, just don't like throwing strings in general, since it could lead to some issues as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502052/throwing-strings-instead-of-errors. The new Error part was just my suggestion but is indeed not completely equivalent to the example shown in the original post ;)

Comment: I agree with that, but if you refactor existing code, it should be equivalent. Because you never know if the rejected value is used as string somewhere. But it for sure should be mentioned that `new Error` is better.

Comment: @t.niese fair enough, since an exact equivalent was provided in an answer above I'll keep this one like this for reference sake

Answer (score -2):

The `Promise` callback isn't async

```
async function uploadMultipleFiles (storageFilePaths,packFilePaths,packRoot) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            for (i in storageFilePaths) {
                await uploadFile(storageFilePaths[i],packFilePaths[i],packRoot) // error throws on this line
            }
            resolve("files uploaded")
        } catch {
            console.log(err)
            reject("fail")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Making the callback to `new Promise` an asynchronous function is a definite [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036229/is-it-an-anti-pattern-to-use-async-await-inside-of-a-new-promise-constructor).