# throw Exception('oops!') vs throw 'oops!'

Tags: dart

I notices some code that made me think the `Exception` function call was optional? E.g., do these two lines perform the same function?

```
throw Exception('oops!');
throw 'oops!'
```

Comment: I think this reduces to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/2557263

Comment: [_"You can also throw arbitrary objects..._"](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#throw)

Comment: @Alejandro That question is about JavaScript.  Dart is notably different in that Dart has static types, which provide a big reason why the distinction matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
The former, `throw Exception('oops!');`, creates a new `Exception` object using the `Exception` constructor, then throws that object.
It can be caught by `try { ... } on Exception catch (e) { ... }`.

The latter, `throw 'oops!';` throws the string object.
It can be caught by `try { ... } on String catch (e) { ... }`.

Generally, you shouldn't be doing *either*.

If someone made an error, something that would have been nice to catch at compile-time and reject the program, but which happens to not be that easy to detect, throw an `Error` (preferably some suitable subclass of `Error`).
Errors are not intended to be caught, but to make the program fail visibly. Some frameworks do catch errors and log them instead. They're typically able to restart the code which failed and carry on, without needing to understand why.

If your code hit some exceptional situation which the caller should be made aware of (and which prevents just continuing), throw a *specific subclass* of `Exception`, one which contains the information the caller needs to *programmatically* handle that situation. Document that the code throws this particular exception. It's really a different kind of return value more than it's an error report. Exceptions are *intended* to be caught and handled. Not handling an exception is, itself, an error (which is why it's OK for an uncaught exception to also make the program fail visibly).

If you're debugging, by all means `throw "WAT!";` all you want. Just remove it before you release the code.