# How to use `throw` properly in try...catch block when other unexpected errors might occur?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, throw

The title may not be the best.

Code sample:

```js
a = 1;
try {
   if (a == 1) {
      throw ('My fake error.');
   }
} catch (err) {
   console.log(err.message);
}
```

Assume I have more complex code in the `try` block. If a statement in that `try` block throws an error I can get the text of the error by looking at `err.message`. But, if I `throw` an error myself I can only see the text if I look at `err` because `err.message` is undefined.

How do I catch both unexpected errors, and errors I `throw` in the same catch block without writing more complex code to see if `err.message` is `null` for instance? I would expect both to return a similar structure, but they do not.

Comment: "*if I `throw` an error myself*" - well the problem is you're **not** [throwing an `Error` as you should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572), you're throwing a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach to this sort of issue is to [always throw Error objects, and not literals](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-throw-literal).

> It is considered good practice to only throw the Error object itself or an object using the Error object as base objects for user-defined exceptions. The fundamental benefit of Error objects is that they automatically keep track of where they were built and originated.

If you throw a plain non-error value, that value will be the expression in the `catch` section - which will (probably) not have the `.message` (or `.stack`) property, and be less than useful as a result.

So, replace `throw ('My fake error.');` with `throw new Error('My fake error.');` - and then, in `catch`, doing `console.log(err.message)` may log either `My fake error.`, or it may log whatever other unexpected error occurred, if the rest of the code around there is well structured enough to always throw Error objects. Just enabling and following that `no-throw-literal` ESLint rule referenced above would be sufficient.