# Troubleshooting "Non-Error promise rejection captured with value: Object Not Found Matching Id" in Sentry, from MERN App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, sentry

[image]

This is an issue we've had for a while now, although this error has recently been appearing much more frequently for us in Sentry. Clicking into the issue does not give us much more info:

[image]

Like any painful error, we are having difficulty recreating the issue on our end - going to these website URLs does not cause this issue locally for me (although, I am on Mac, not Windows). A few related questions we have:

- is this something we can safely ignore in Sentry?
- if safe to ignore, is it better to ignore in the Sentry website in the Browser by clicking the **ignore** button, or by adding `ignoreErrors` into our `Sentry.init()` with

We initialize Sentry in our React App with this snippet in our **index.js** file:

```
Sentry.init({
    dsn: config.dsn,
    integrations: [
        new Integrations.BrowserTracing()
    ],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0
});
```

and we initialize in our **Node App** in it's `index.js` file:

```
const sentryDsn = env === 'development' ? null : config.SENTRY_DSN;
Sentry.init({ dsn: sentryDsn, tracesSampleRate: 1.0 });
```

I show both initializations as I am not sure if this is an error coming from our React app or our Node App, although I think it's from our React App. Also, from [this article](https://forum.sentry.io/t/unhandledrejection-non-error-promise-rejection-captured-with-value/14062/14), it seems like we could ignore these errors directly from our app with the following added to `Sentry.init({})`:

```
ignoreErrors:[
   "Non-Error exception captured",
   "Non-Error promise rejection captured"
]
```

We also found this [related github issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3440), although it doesn't seem like there are any great conclusions in here as well. Any recommendations as to what our best course of action is here, and how we could potentially further troubleshoot this, would be super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured out where this error is coming from?

Comment: The actual error that you need to find and fix is "*Object Not Found Matching Id*". That some code threw this as a string (apparently?) and not a `new Error` [as recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572) is just informational and the reason why you didn't get a proper stack trace. This might make debugging harder, but it is not a valid reason to ignore the error.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested in the GitHub issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/3440#issuecomment-865857552), it seems to be caused due an issue with Outlook. Given that most of the users are coming from Windows, I'd say it's safe ignoring.