# Is it wrong to throw something other than an Error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

In exceptional circumstances in javascript code, you can break out of the current control flow by `throw`ing, e.g.:

```
throw new Error('Something unexpected occurred.');
```

What's the point of instantiating an `Error`, when you can also just throw a `String`:

```
throw 'Something unexpected occurred.';
```

Comment: its up to you what you do.

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't know that. @DanielA.White

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, it's specifically about throwing strings.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, but still should be closed. New close reason would be "primarily opinion based"

Comment: The difference between throwing a string and an error is covered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13016600/1529630) of the dupe.