# purposely throw error in a promise?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to purposely make a promise fail? Sometime I just skip the test and assume everything is fine, but I want to purposely make the promise to fail so that my catch is working.

```
exports.submitJob = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { cv } = req.body
    const userId = req.user._id

    try {

      if(!cv) {
        //how to pass error to catch block?
      }
      const save_submission = new Submission({
        userId,
        cv
      }).save()


    } catch(e => {
      res.json({
        status: 0,
        error: e
      })
    })

    next()
}
```

Comment: Did you try to throw an Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `throw new Error('<your string here>');`:

Note that `catch` is not something to be used with `function` syntax - the proper syntax is `catch (e) { /* block that uses e */ }`

```js
const submitJobWhichWillFail = async (req, res, next) => {
  const cv = null;
  try {
    if (!cv) {
      throw new Error('cv must not be falsey!');
    }
    const save_submission = new Submission({
      userId,
      cv
    }).save()


  } catch (e) {
    console.log('res.json with error ' + e);
  }
}
submitJobWhichWillFail();
```

Comment: Why `throw('something is wrong')` also worked? i tried without the `new`, just `throw Error('something is wrong')` worked too.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156176/what-is-the-difference-between-throw-new-error-and-throw-someobject#answer-13016600) and the one below it - `throw new Error` is said to be more reliable, though it probably doesn't matter as much nowadays because more browsers are standards-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

use the [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#throw_statement) statement, maybe?

```
if(!cv) {throw("cv is absent");}
```

user-defined exception-types (alike one commonly has them in Java or PHP) are also possible and recommended, because one barely can differ the type by a string and otherwise can easily check the `typeof` the exception in the `catch` block. just learned from the MDN, that one eg. can also throw [DOMException](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException/DOMException) and [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).