# Throw await syntax in Nodejs async express handler is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
const express = require("express");
const expressAsyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const app = express();

const f = async () => {
  return false;
};

app.get(
  "/",
  expressAsyncHandler(async () => {
    throw await f();
  }),
  () => {
    console.log("the bug!");
  }
);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("caught!", err);
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("listening on port 4000..."));
```

Expected output on the console:

"caught!".

output:

the bug!.

question: Why? Is it a bug in async-express-handler package or is it a normal JavaScript behaviour? what if I want to **throw await** something inside? how ?

Comment: This is the entire soruce code: https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler/blob/master/index.js The error is just caught so nothing is passed to your error handler.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, important, I updated the code, I caught another bug

Comment: I don't see a bug here. Why wouldn't the next middleware run when the error is handled already?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, ha?

Comment: Error is handled by the `catch` so it's not unhandled anymore and code can proceed

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, but I never called next anywhere

Comment: It's called in the library `Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next)`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, okay then it's unwanted behavior.

Comment: common man just say yes

Comment: What you're not getting is the standard behavior is for a Promise to call the `reject` method when the `resolve` method throws an exception.  There's nothing to see here.  Move along.

Comment: We will know when maintainers  will answer on [your issue](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler/issues/55)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're `throw`ing the value `false`. This doesn't fit into [nodejs' callback conventions](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/) (and by extension, [express error handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)), which requires the `err` parameter to get a truthy value to be considered an error. A much simpler way to reproduce the issue:

```
app.get(
  "/",
  (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.reject(false).catch(next);
    // or even just:
    next(false);
  },
  () => {
    console.log("the bug!");
  }
);
```

So just don't do that! Always `throw` an `Error`, [not a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572), [not something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9156176/1048572), and this principle [also holds for promise rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26020578/1048572).